# 'Globalize' Bash functions inside of a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Alright, so let's say I have a .bash file with this inside of it

lib.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello_world {
     echo "Hello World!"
}
```

That file won't be called on it's own, instead it'll be called via another bash file, i.e

Startup.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
bash lib.bash
hello_world
```

But, if I run Startup.bash I get the error: `hello_world: command not found`

What am I doing wrong, or is it not possible to do what I'm trying to do on bash.

Comment: You can try `source lib.bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command in your `startup.bash`:

```
source lib.bash
```

the `source` command runs the file in the **current** shell environment, unlike using `bash lib.bash` 
(or `. lib.bash`) which creates a **new**, separate environment for that script (and only that script) and is why the function is not carried over.

([source](https://superuser.com/a/618442))

Comment: Source works, the reason why I hadn't used it before is since every time I used it in what I'm truly using it for; it didn't work. But, it turns out it was an error on my part that caused it to not work, so it does now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

why don't you call the function directly inside of the first script?

It would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello_world {
     echo "Hello World!"
}
hello_world
```

If it is a simple script, shouldn't be a problem at all.
Otherwise try the source command, like minerz029 suggested :)

Comment: Because I wanted the function to be independent from the main file.

Answer (score 0):

See if this could be helpful to you as well:

[Shell Script Loader](http://loader.sourceforge.net/)